# how to stitch dataframes together

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to join five dataframes together in pandas in jupyter notebook, I've already tried using merge/concat/join/append functions but they returned a cartesian product/ too many rows. All my dataframes have rows(repetitive but different column values) and columns(different no. of columns in different dataframes)`enter code here`. I don't want an inner or left join. For instance, for a DF of dimensions 8*4 and 5*3 (rows * columns) my output should be 10*6 as shown in images. Joins are giving way too many rows.

[First example DF1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shYCz.png)

[Second example DF2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neuMH.png)

[Final output DF after combining DF1 &DF2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qvemf.png)

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `azure-notebooks` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Hey, I think it would help if you included code snippets and column headers for your data frames as it is hard for moderators to get the details.
you can refer to the [guidelines ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a better understanding on how to ask a good question

Comment: As suggested I've included sample DF's along with the desired output.

Comment: @nickthefreak could you kindly look into this now....Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to join/concat the two frames. the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) explains how it works in detail, but I believe in your case it would look like this:

```
result = pd.concat([df1, df4], axis=1, join='outer', sort=True)
```

Thanks for updating your question; it's still not 100% clear so try to include some information about what you've tried, any errors or what documentation you looked to make sure that no effort is duplicated and your question is not taken off.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for append

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

From the docs:
"
Append rows of other to the end of caller, returning a new object.

Columns in other that are not in the caller are added as new columns.
"

If want to append "side to side" rather than "top to bottom", then do a transpose of the df, append, and transpose back.

Comment: NO, Thanks for your suggestion!! also made some modifications  now for more clarity

Comment: Append did not work for me. Also I've updated the question so you might get more clarity now, awaiting your response.